# CSS drop-shadow filter makes fonts blurry on mobile

Tags: css

I have a text with `drop-shadow` filter, on desktop looks good but on mobile (Firefox / Chrome / Safari) the text is pixelated.

No issues on desktop, I tried with some suggestion like `blur(0px)` and `translateZ(0)` but nothing changed.

Without `drop-shadow`

[image]

With `drop-shadow`

[image]

**CSS**

```
.my-text {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-filter:
  drop-shadow(0px 0px 3px #000)
  blur(0px);
  filter:
  drop-shadow(0px 0px 3px #000)
  blur(0px);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent loss of quality on mobile?

Comment: Please try to add `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` 

Comment: Tried but no luck :(

Comment: I tested on iOS ... for me it is as you wrote it -- not -- pixelated.

Comment: If you compare two screenshots with and without drop-shadow you should notice a change in quality.

Comment: I am saying two things. 1. It is -- not -- on every browser. 2. Now I have no way to test. 

Comment: Note that no browser has needed the -webkit vendor prefix for filter in 120 years. I might be exaggerating.